# what are the best practices for bulk upload of .csv file in Django?

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-orm

I have a simple CSV file upload module to bulk upload my POS data. Sample Code below..

models.py

```
class POSData(models.Model):
    outlet_name = models.CharField(...)
    food_item = models.ForeignKey('FoodItem', ...)
    order_date = models.DateField(...)
    ...


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(...)
    ...


class FoodItem(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(...)
    item_key = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    ...


class RecipeItem(models.Model):
    food_item = models.ForeignKey(FoodItem, ...)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, ...)
    quantity = models.Charfield(...)
    ...


class POSIngredientData(models.Model):
    outlet_name = models.CharField(...)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, ...)
    quantity = models.Charfield(...)
    order_date = models.DateField(...)
    ...
```

views.py  #Code sample for handling .csv file upload

```
    file = request.FILES['order_file']
    decoded_file = file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()

    # creating a csv dictionary reader object
    csvDictReader = csv.DictReader(decoded_file, delimiter=',')
    
    for obj in csvDictReader:
        try:
            food_item = FoodItem.objects.get(item_key=obj['item_key'])
        except FoodItem.DoesNotExist:
            # Do Something Here
            pass
        POSData.objects.create(food_item=food_item, ...)
        
        recipesItemQS = RecipeItem.objects.filter(food_item=food_item)

        # uploading POS data of ingredients in separate model to help in qs
        # Average 10 ingredients in a foodItem recipe
        for recipeItem in recipesItemQS:
            POSIngredientData.objects.create(ingredient=recipeItem.ingredient, ...)
```

My question is that, it takes too long to upload all the data to database(5-10 seconds to upload one row of .csv file). **Is there any more efficient way to upload bulk data from .csv file?** Also, I read somewhere that the **Model.save()** method should be used instead of **Model.create()** for bulk upload.  *I couldn't figure out why as Model.create() uses the same save() method*.

I am new to Django and am learning by making errors and practising. Please accept my apologies if the question is not correctly phrased or if there is any grammatical error.

Comment: Is your CSV file contains multiple model fields value?

Comment: No, it just contains fields from the POSData model. What if it does contain multiple model fields value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can use [`.bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

You can first create a normal object list of POSIngredientData and add it inside the objs parameter of `.bulk_create()` like this

```
listOfPosIngredient = [POSIngredientData(ingredient=recipeItem.ingredient) for recipeItem in recipesItemQS] #Creates a list of POSIngredientData objects
POSIngredientData.objects.bulk_create(listOfPosIngredient) #Calls the bulk create method to push everything in ONE QUERY.
```

**Method 2**

You can also use a neat django plugin called [django-import-export](http://%20https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which is also compatible with django admin.

Comment: Thank you @Ruchit for answering my question. I read the Django documentation for the **.bulk_create() method**, which answered most of my queries about bulk upload. I won't be able to upvote your response since I don't have enough reputation.